# Wordpress plugin require_once unexpected

Tags: plugins

I am making a plugin, and for some reason, it is now saying the first line is "unexpected," no matter what it is.

It was working fine before, I made an edit at the bottom of the file, but have since removed it and reuploaded, and it is still throwing the error.

For a second it switched to and "invalid header" error.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
/*
*Plugin Name: Products Tools
*Description: products widget
*/
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'get-product.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'output.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'shortcode.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'all-products.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'add-templates.php');
//require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'products-json.php');
//require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'create-page.php');
//require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'widget.php');
//require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'widget2.php');



function product_box_cpt() {

register_post_type( 'product', array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
   ),
  'description' => 'Hosting Prodcuts.',
  'public' => true,
  'menu_position' => 8,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ),
  'has_archive' => 'products'
));
}
```

and the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE) in /home/davidmno/public_html/beadedtreasures/wp-content/plugins/product-box/product-box.php on line 1

The thing is, if I comment out the require lines, then it just says "unexpected function"...  It seems like whatever php is calling it could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try disabling all other plugins and switch to Wordpress standard twenty fifteen theme?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but is there any possibility your text editor is encoding the file in UTF-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? Try to save / encode the file in UTF-8 without BOM and see if the issue is gone.

As for your plugin header, while it doesn't totally follow the [recommended format](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L17) your header should still be parsed correctly since this is what the main code looks like for parsing the header:

```
preg_match( '/^[ \t\/*#@]*' . preg_quote( $regex, '/' ) . ':(.*)$/mi', $file_data, $match )
```

Notice that you can in fact have spaces / tabs / asterisk at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I did check that.  no dice. :/